# Gallery app, if Selected photos width large to height, photos seems vertical

Tags: android

I try a gallery app.
My app working  2 diffrent form.
From the Gallery or from camera selection,
if selected photos height large to width everything ok.
if Selected photos width large to height, photos seems vertical

Example,
This image width : 3264, height : 2448

[image]

My app in seems like this;

[image]

this is my decode size code, Sorry bad english, thank you.

```
private class DecodeSize extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap> {

        private int reqWidth;
        private int reqHeight;
        private ImageView imageView;
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

        private DecodeSize(int reqWidth, int reqHeight, ImageView imageView) {
            this.reqWidth = reqWidth;
            this.reqHeight = reqHeight;
            this.imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }


        public int calculateInSampleSize( BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
            // Raw height and width of image
            final int height = options.outHeight;
            final int width = options.outWidth;

            int inSampleSize = 1;

            if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

                final int halfHeight = height / 2;
                final int halfWidth = width / 2;

                // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
                // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
                while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                        && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                    inSampleSize *= 2;
                }
            }

            return inSampleSize;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            String photo_path = params[0];

            // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo_path, options);

            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo_path, options);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if(imageViewReference != null && bitmap !=null) {
                final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void decodeSizeFunction(String picturePath) {
        decodeSize = new DecodeSize(200,200,foto_image);
        decodeSize.execute(picturePath);
    }
```

Comment: use android query for image resizing and scaling.

Comment: I try picasso library but other problems appeared